# Can you identify this bee?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found on the ground on dried cottonwood leaves in southern Utah.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a species of [Megachilidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megachilidae) family of bees, solitary and leaf eaters, covered in pollens.

It could be from Genus *Megachile*.

All its identifying features are hidden though:

> T1 segments have 2 “sides”, one that faces forward or faces the thorax and one that faces the top.[$^1$](http://bugguide.net/node/view/1280401)
>
> In Megachile, the “corner” where the forward side and the top side meet is severe. It creates a flat or concave appearance like a circular shelf.[$^2$](http://bugguide.net/node/view/251430)

This genus it comparable to *Lithurgopsis* which

> has a more gradual transition to the "sides" of T1.[$^3$](http://bugguide.net/node/view/1056584)

<sub>(Source: [bugnet](http://bugguide.net/node/view/7751))</sub>

Comment: @MikePasichnyk I didn't ID this correctly. Your bee shouldn't be a leaf eater, as the  pollen-carrying structures of this family are restricted to the ventral surface of abdomen. So it is anything other than this family. I'd like to remove this answer which is possible only if you uncheck it.

Answer (score 2):

Tyto is correct, it's not a megachilid. It looks like it's probably in the genus Andrena to me, you can see deep, hairy fovea at the top of the head.